# Convert SDT data to BC in Genexus

Tags: dataprovider, genexus, bc

I populated a SDT with data in Genexus 15 and need to save it on a transaction. The SDT has a two level structure with header information and detail items.

I tried with this DataProvider but something is wrong, because I get an foreign key violation error when tring to execute it:

Rules:

```
parm(in: &NewInvoice); // SDT variable
```

Source:

```
DPInvoice 
{
    StampId = &NewInvoice.StampId
    InvoiceNumber = &NewInvoice.InvoiceNumber
    CustomerId = &NewInvoice.CustomerId
    Concept
    {
        ProductId = &NewInvoice.Concept.CurrentItem.ProductId
        ConceptQty = &NewInvoice.Concept.CurrentItem.ConceptQty
    }
}
```

The Event triggering the DP in the webpanel:

```
&Invoice = DPInvoice(&NewInvoice)
&Invoice.Insert()
commit
```

[This is the transaction structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yiv9.png)

[This is the SDT Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvYhu.png)

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the second level of `&NewInvoice`.

Define a variable `&NewInvoiceItem` of type `SDTInvoiceCopy1.ConceptItem` in the DataProvider and use the following Source code:

```
DPInvoice 
{
    StampId = &NewInvoice.StampId
    InvoiceNumber = &NewInvoice.InvoiceNumber
    CustomerId = &NewInvoice.CustomerId
    Concept Input &NewInvoiceItem in &NewInvoice.Concept
    {
        ProductId = &NewInvoiceItem.ProductId
        ConceptQty = &NewInvoiceItem.ConceptQty
    }
}
```